# literal list/array of class types

Tags: objective-c

In objective c, how can you declare a list that contains types? What I'm wanting to do is have a list of specific class types, and then check if a particular object's class is in that list.

pseudo code:

```
SET class_list TO [MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3]
SET input_class_type TO class of input_object
FOR each current_class_type in class_list
   IF input_class_type is same class type as current_class_type
      return TRUE
END LOOP
return FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *classes = @[[NSArray class], [NSDictionary class], [NSSet class]];
id inputObject = [NSSet new];

for (Class class in classes) {
    if ([inputObject isKindOfClass: class]) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

You generally want `isKindOfClass`, which also checks whether the type is a subclass of the given type. If you want to know that it's exactly the same class, you can use `isMemberOfClass`, but you can often be surprised. For example:

```
[[NSSet new] isMemberOfClass:[NSSet class]] == false
```

!!!!

Why is an NSSet not an NSSet? Because NSSet is a class cluster, and in this case the "real" type is an internal implementation subclass called __NSSetI. That kind of thing happens a lot in Objective-C, so you usually mean `isKindOfClass` unless you have a very special need.